# How to get the actual coordinate for all of the joint?

Tags: c++, rostopic, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi. I'm new to ROS Indigo. Is regarding the actual joint states, I have tried the rostopic echo /joint_states and /tf, but it seems like the joint_states and tf are keep on going non stop. May I know is it a way to only acquire one of joint's joint states instead of all of the joint and not in array form?

Also, I have tried with rostopic echo /arm_1/arm_controller/position_command and rostopic echo /arm_1/gripper_controller/position_command, but it did not return any message back to me, the process is just empty.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/323046/how-to-get-the-actual-coordinate-for-all-of-the-joint?/) by [Shuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/41507/shuu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-05-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Reamees](https://answers.ros.org/users/36207/reamees/) on 2019-05-13**:
`rosrun tf view_frames` - will generate a pdf of the tf tree and save where your terminal is currently

`rosrun rqt_tf_tree rqt_tf_tree` - will show that same tree in a rqt plugin

`rosrun tf tf_echo /base_link /gripper` - will print out the transforms between the two links if it is being published

`rostopic echo /joint_states -n 1` will print only 1 message  from the topic [joint_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_publisher)

If you need any other info please provide more specific info on what you would like to achieve.

**Comment by [Shuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/41507/shuu/) on 2019-05-13**:
Thanks for your reply. but I would like to know the actual coordinate* of each of the joint instead of angle, because I will substitute the angles for each of the joint in forward kinematic, while want the feedback of each of the x,y,z coordinate of each of the joint.  Thanks

**Comment by [Shuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/41507/shuu/) on 2019-05-13**:
I wonder with the rosrun tf tf_echo /base_link /gripper, if gives out the transform between two links, but is it possible that i want the transform of one link only, in order to get their specific coordinate? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> is it possible that i want the transform of one link only, in order to get their specific coordinate?

To get the coordinates of a joint you need a fixed frame (such as `world` or `map`) otherwise any joint could have any coordinates depending the frame you are reading the coordinates from.

```
rosrun tf tf_echo /world /joint
```

This command can give you the coordinates of a specific joint in the world (can be `map` or any other frame that is fixed in your world). You will be able to read those coordinates in the terminal but given what you said I assume you actually want to get those coordinates in your code to process them.

You will achieve that using `tf` by checking the transformation between your reference frame and your desired joint. Here's an example using `geometry_msgs::PoseStamped` (to get `x`, `y`, `z`) to constantly get the coordinates of a joint :

```
//Required includes
#include <tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h>
#include <tf2_ros/transform_listener.h>

tf2_ros::Buffer tf_; 
geometry_msgs::PoseStamped joint_global_frame_pose_stamped;
geometry_msgs::PoseStamped joint_pose_stamped;
//Just an initialization
tf2::toMsg(tf2::Transform::getIdentity(), joint_global_frame_pose_stamped.pose);
tf2::toMsg(tf2::Transform::getIdentity(), joint_pose_stamped.pose);
ros::Rate rate(10.0);
while(ros::ok())
{
    //The frame you want to get the pose 
    joint_pose_stamped.header.frame_id = "joint";
    joint_pose_stamped.header.stamp = ros::Time();
    //Catch exceptions
    try
    {
        //3rd param = The global frame
        tf_.transform(joint_pose_stamped, joint_global_frame_pose_stamped, "map");  
    }
    catch (tf2::LookupException& ex)
    {
        ROS_ERROR_THROTTLE(1.0, "No Transform available Error looking up joint pose: %s\n", ex.what());
    }
    catch (tf2::ConnectivityException& ex)
    {
        ROS_ERROR_THROTTLE(1.0, "Connectivity Error looking up joint pose: %s\n", ex.what());
    }
    catch (tf2::ExtrapolationException& ex)
    {
        ROS_ERROR_THROTTLE(1.0, "Extrapolation Error looking up joint pose: %s\n", ex.what());
    }

    ROS_INFO("The joint position is { %.2f; %.2f; %.2f}", 
            joint_global_frame_pose_stamped.pose.postion.x,
            joint_global_frame_pose_stamped.pose.postion.y,
            joint_global_frame_pose_stamped.pose.postion.z);
}
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2019-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Shuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/41507/shuu/) on 2019-05-15**:
Hi,  thanks for your reply. I have tried  with
"rosrun tf tf_echo /arm_link_1 /arm_link_5", it works and I got the transformation from link 1 to link 5. Thanks.

**Comment by [Shuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/41507/shuu/) on 2019-05-15**:
Sorry, one more question. If i find rosrun tf tf_echo /arm_link_0 /arm_link_4, the coordinate or translation they give is not my joint 3 coordinate is it? If not, how do I find the joints coordinate?

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-05-16**:
When you are referring to specific joints/links that could be useful to provide the urdf or tf tree so that we can understand what you are talking about ;)

When you do a `tf_echo frame_A frame_B` you just get the transform to go from `frame_A` to `frame_B`.

> the coordinate or translation they give
> is not my joint 3 coordinate is it?

As said previsously it's a translation and rotation so that you can use it to transform coordinates from a frame to another.
If you want your joint coordinates, since the joint is the origin of the related frame then the translation from `tf_echo` is directly the coordinates of the joint.

So if your `joint3` has `child_link` to `/arm_link4` and you want its coordinates in `/arm_link_0` frame you just have to get the translation from `rosrun tf tf_echo /arm_link0 /arm_link4`. This will give you the coordinates of `/arm_link4` frame (i.e. your `joint3` coordinates) within `/arm_link0` frame.

**Comment by [Shuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/41507/shuu/) on 2019-05-16**:
Thanks about that. I found out that actually my coding reference point and the ros's reference point is different. After do some calculation using trigonometry and deduction or addition, my x-axis coordinate is kind of similar to the actual x coordinate from the rosrun tf, just some +/-0.01 difference. However, my z-axis has the value that has a lot of different, compared with the actual z coordinate. Is it that I cannot apply trigonometry function to get the z-axis? Though I got the x-axis , which is almost similar.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-05-17**:\

> my coding reference point and the ros's reference point is different

What are they ?

> After do some calculation using trigonometry and deduction or addition

What calculations ?

You need to be more specific as we don't have access to your code/project, like maybe just show the code doing those calculations.

**Comment by [Shuu](https://answers.ros.org/users/41507/shuu/) on 2019-05-17**:
Coding reference point is at the joint 1 as shown in here [coding](https://github.com/arifanjum/ROS-YouBot-Inverse-Kinematics/blob/master/Zero%20Reference%20Point%20%26%20Reference%20Position.png), meanwhile the reference point from the ros is different since the transformation from base to joint 1 is not (0,0,0) instead (0,024,0.0.96). If the joint 1 and 0 is located at the same position as shown in the [coding](https://github.com/arifanjum/ROS-YouBot-Inverse-Kinematics/blob/master/Zero%20Reference%20Point%20%26%20Reference%20Position.png), the transformation of link 1 should be (0,0,0) right?

The calculation I did it manually, but is based on the three set of thing, which are the coordinate I set for the tip of the end effector, coordinate of joint 3 and the coordinate for the object's center point, where the tip of the end effector and joint 3 are parallel in x axis.

**Comment by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) on 2019-05-17**:
Can you give another picuture showing the real tfs in rviz ? Because I can't actually see where are `base_link` frame nor `link_1` frame. (or I didn't understand your picture, the white circle represent the base_link frame and the frame on top of it is link_1 frame ?).

> the coordinate for the object's center point

You are mixing things with [#q323256](https://answers.ros.org/question/323256/how-to-ensure-the-tip-of-the-end-effector-is-facing-toward-the-center-of-the-object/). I feel this question doesn't need further comments since you managed to get the coordinate of your joint, other questions should be asked within  [#q323256](https://answers.ros.org/question/323256/how-to-ensure-the-tip-of-the-end-effector-is-facing-toward-the-center-of-the-object/) or in a new one.